# Macos Could NOT identify C/C++ compiler because compilation failed

Tags: drake

I am getting this error when trying to compile on drake macos 10.14.6. I have ran the setup script.

Bazel: 2.0.0

Drake 0.11.0

```
lawn-143-215-113-3:drake tdogb$ bazel build //...
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'cc' which is a cc_repository (rule definition at /Users/tdogb/drake/tools/workspace/cc/repository.bzl:147:1
7):
 - /Users/tdogb/drake/tools/workspace/default.bzl:110:9
 - /Users/tdogb/drake/WORKSPACE:10:1
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'cc':
   attribute : Could NOT identify C/C++ compiler because compilation failed.
ERROR: no such package '@cc//': attribute : Could NOT identify C/C++ compiler because compilation failed.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.221s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
    currently loading: attic/util ... (145 packages)
lawn-143-215-113-3:drake tdogb$
```

Answer (score 0):

From the https://drake.mit.edu/release_notes/release_notes.html list of dependencies over time, Drake 0.11.0 is probably not compatible with Bazel 2.0.0.  Try Bazel 1.1.0 or 1.0.0 instead.